# Find minimal sum between multiple sums of rows which belong to dates

Tags: sql, hive, window

I'm using a Hive database and trying to do the following:

There is a transactional table with date/store/product/movetype/stock (meaning that to find the stock value of a certain product that sits in a certain store on a certain day one has to
SELECT DATE, STORE, PRODUCT, SUM(stock_value) GROUP BY 1,2,3 because there may be many product movements in a day and the final stock value consists of their sum).

My current goal is to find the min value of stock for last 14 days and add it as a field to the stock table to see if the stock value suffered any painful drops for the last two weeks.

Tried this one:
`select min(stock_value) over (partition by store, product order by calendar_date range between 13 preceding and current row)`

However, as I said earlier, the table includes several different 'product movement types' , some of which are negative numbers. So that means that I'm getting not the minimal **day** value, but (seemingly) the minimal value among every row of those 14 days. Looking for a way to sum values as first step of a window function, and to find the minumum of those multiple sums as second step.

I understand that there's ways to use subqueries or CTEs for that goal, but I believe a window function would be more efficient, if there's a possibility to use it in that situation.

Thank you in advance!